# save the value of an input in a variable in angular 5

Tags: angular, html, angular-ngmodel

I am new at angular and I am trying to get the value of an input and save it in a variable to pass it to my service that needs a parameter:

## this is my html

```
<form class="main-form">

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="cedula">Numero de cedula</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula [(ngModel)]="cedula" placeholder="Ingrese su numero de cedula">
   <br>
   <button type="submit" (click)="getReservas(cedula)" class="btn btn-primary">Consultar</button>

  </div>

</form>
<h1>Usuario Reservado</h1>
<div class="clear"></div>
<table class="table" >
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Cedula</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Edad</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Origen</th>
      <th scope="col">Destino</th>
      <th scope="col">Hora</th>
      <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of reserva">

      <td>{{item.cedula}}</td>
      <td>{{item.nombre}}</td>
      <td>{{item.edad}}</td>
      <td>{{item.fechar}}</td>
      <td>{{item.origenr}}</td>
      <td>{{item.destinor}}</td>
      <td>{{item.hora}}</td>
      <td>{{item.telefono}}</td>
      <td>{{item.precior}}</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

### this is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

import {ReservasService} from './reservas.service';
import {ReservasModel} from './../modelo/reservas.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reservas',
  templateUrl: './reservas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reservas.component.css'],
  providers:[ReservasService]
})
export class ReservasComponent implements OnInit {
    private reserva:Array<ReservasModel>;
    private cedula:String;
  constructor(private rs:ReservasService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadRes();
  }

private loadRes():void{
    this.rs.getReservas(this.cedula).subscribe(res=>{
        this.reserva=res;

    });
}
}
```

#### my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import  {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import {ReservasModel} from './../modelo/reservas.model';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReservasService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public getReservas(cedula:String):Observable<ReservasModel[]>{

    return this.http.get<ReservasModel[]>("http://localhost:8080/getConsultarCc?cc="+cedula);

  }
}
```

what am I doing wrong, I would thank whoever can help me.

try this form but I get error:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39959287/10543023 and https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5845

Comment: You have got a typo in your template `<input name="cedula [(ngModel)]="cedula">`, add a `"` after `cedula`.

Comment: **My friend has already corrected the quotes but it still does not work and I get this error:**ERROR TypeError: _co.getReservas is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ReservasComponent.html:7)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11047)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7710)
    at core.js:8154

Answer (score 3):

You are missing closing the `"` in the input field. You should be closing the `"` in order for the angular two way binding to work using `ngModel`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" [(ngModel)]="cedula" placeholder="Ingrese su numero de cedula">
```

**TS**

```
private cedula:string;
```

I full working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfjpgu

**Two more things:**

1) Also you should be using `string` instead of `String`. Take a look to the answers here: [Typescript: difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string)

2)if you are going to be using private variables make sure you use getters and setters. I don't suggest you to make them private unless they are for constructors or classes. it's not good practice to not declare getters and setters on private variables in the components.

[Typescript Class with private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380542/typescript-class-with-private-variables). If you decide to leave the private varible change your code after you have created the setters.

```
private loadRes():void{
    this.rs.getReservas(this.getCedula()).subscribe(res=>{
        this.reserva=res;

    });
}
```

Comment: friend and I corrected the quotes and change the String string but it still does not work and I get the same error as always:             ERROR TypeError: _co.getReservas is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ReservasComponent.html:7)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11047)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7710)
    at core.js:8154
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:988)